# python sax parser skipping over exception

Tags: python, xml, sax

Is there a way to "skip" a line using a SAX XML parser?

I've got a non-confirming XML document which is a concatenation of valid XML documents and thus the `<?xml ...?>` appears for each document.  Also note I need to use a SAX parser since the input documents are huge.

I tried crafting a "custom stream" class as feeder for the parser but quickly realized that SAX uses the `read` method and thus reads stuff in "byte arrays" thereby exploding the complexity of this project.

thanks!

**UPDATE:** I know there is way around this using `csplit` but I am after a Python based solution if at all possible within reasonable limits.

**Update2:** Maybe I should have said "skipping to next document", that would have made more sense. Anyhow, that's what I need: a way of parsing multiple documents from a single input stream.

Comment: Not only the directive `<?xml ...?>` but well formed xml documents need a root element, skipping that line you get again a xml document not well formed. You cannot just append one xml file to another one, parse one and then the other.

Comment: Invent a sort of protocol: four bytes that are the length of the XML document and to follow the document itself, read the document and parse it with sax. The next four bytes are the length of the next xml document, read it and parse it, and so on.

Comment: Let me guess - you have buggy XML from an early version of NCBI BLAST? That's the only example I know of concatenated XML files.

Comment: nope... google patent documents...

Comment: camt054 notifications look the same

Answer (score 0):

When you are concatenating the documents together, just replace the beginning <? and ?> with <!-- and -->, this will comment out the xml declarations.

Comment: can't: I would need to process the whole file beforehand... the reason  I want to use a SAX parser is to sidestep this process.

Comment: Can you replace the declaration and add a root element when the files are concatenated?